# Azure SQL Server CE Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-ce

I have developed a C# .Net web application where I have Simple Membership enabled and pointing to a SQL Server CE database located in the App_Data directory. When I run the site locally it is fine and I can register and logon to the application fine. Issue is when I publish it to Azure I get the following error when trying to logon:

**Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0**

So I have done a bit of searching around but cannot find a specific resolution to this issue. Snippets of my web.config contain the following:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" />
</appSettings>


<DbProviderFactories>
  <clear />
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.6.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
</DbProviderFactories>

<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MySQLOrderTrackerConnectionString" connectionString="XXXX;Database=OrderTracker;uid=XXXX;pwd=XXXX" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  <add name="MembershipConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Membership.sdf;password=XXXX" />
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="DefaultConnection_ConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

What is also don't understand is that when published to Azure the DefaultConnection connection string appears. Where sis that come from? But the main issue here is how to resolve the initialization string issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably solved this by now, in case you didn't:

It looks as if you have an issue with the actual connection string. Can you please share (omitting password, hostnames) the actual Azure connection string?

if not, use these as guidelines:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee621781.aspx
- http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure/